# What does "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.ArrayMap.<init>(BZZ)V" mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j

Here's the code and the error. Line 14 in the diagnostic is the only line in the main.

```
import java.io.File;  
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;   

public class testMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File x = new File("c:/temp/foo");
        //      GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "c:/temp/foo" );
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( x );

    }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.ArrayMap.<init>(BZZ)V
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.RagManager.<init>(RagManager.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.community.CommunityLockManger.<init>(CommunityLockManger.java:34)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityEditionModule.createLockManager(CommunityEditionModule.java:247)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityEditionModule.<init>(CommunityEditionModule.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
    at testMain.main(testMain.java:14)
```

Comment: The compiled jar is probably referencing to some other GraphDatabaseFactory class. Are you using maven to build your project? Please check if some dependency of your project also contains org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory

Comment: Just Eclipse, no Maven.

Comment: Loading dependencies as external jars?